# how to get ping result correctly by shell?

Tags: shell

I'm writing shell script, and I want to get ping result, so I write code like this:

```
ping_res=`ping -c 5 $ADMIN_GW -I $SRIOV_BOND | grep loss | awk '{print $6}' | awk -F "%" '{print $1}'`
```

Most PC got this result: '100', some PC got this result: '+5'. So I run command like this to check why:

```
ping_res=`ping -c 5 $ADMIN_GW -I $SRIOV_BOND | grep loss`
```

and I got different result, one is:

```
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4001ms
```

one is:

```
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +5 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4001ms
```

I don't why, and I want to get '100%', so is there some way to get result correctly. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -o '[0-9]\+%'` to isolate that part of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ping-commnad>| grep -Po  '\d+%'
100%
```

Here, `\d` represents a single digit, now `+` sign after it makes at least one or more digit. this is enabled by using `-P` flag which enables `perl`'s regex.